# Using Twitter Bootstrap For 980px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

One of my designer sent me PSD with 980px Width. I want to use Twitter Bootstrap responsive layout for this.

Actually I am back-end developer, I have not much knowledge on front-end.
I found bootstreo container class support 940px.

How can I use it for 980px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get precompiled version with .less files from bootstrap's [github](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and then check for variables.less file. You can specify grid size as you want.

Comment: can you please elaborate more

Comment: go to https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less there at the bottom you will see // Default 940px grid
So just make calculations and change numbers, then recompile all .less files and you should get grid with desired width.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the width in the media queries in bootstrap-responsive.css. They look like:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) {
  /* Your CSS here */
}
```